# Strange Configuration Process

Tags: account-security

I don't know if my question belongs here, but I had a very strange experience with my computer today. I normally put my laptop to sleep when I don't use it, but, today, when I opened it, a booting configuration option for Phoenix Technologies for a Toshiba computer appeared on my screen. My laptop brand is not even Toshiba, so I was puzzled. There seemed to be no way to escape this process, so I pressed the on/off button to restart. Then, my laptop functioned normally. Is this something to be concerned about? What could have been the problem?